# add a json item in json with php

Tags: php, json, angularjs

I am trying to create an angular app with php backend and right now I am stuck with a problem. I have a php code which I will paste it here.

```
<?php
    $textdata = '{"contact_firstname":"Daniel","contact_lastname":"Pacuraru","contact_email":["pacurarudaniel@gmail.com","hello@pacurarudaniel.com"]}';
    $json = json_decode($textdata, true);
    //$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbport = "5432";
    $dbname = "fixevents";
    $dbuser = "postgres";
    $dbpass = "123";
    $connect = pg_connect("host=" . $dbhost . " port=" . $dbport . " dbname=" . $dbname . " user=" . $dbuser . " password=" . $dbpass);

    $query = "INSERT INTO contact (contact_firstname, contact_lastname, contact_email) VALUES ('" . addslashes($json['contact_firstname']) . "', '" . addslashes($json['contact_lastname']) . "', '" . addslashes(implode(',,,', $json['contact_email'])) . "') RETURNING contact_id";
    $result = pg_query($connect, $query);

    $row = pg_fetch_array($result);
    $json_item = 'contact_id' => addslashes($row['contact_id']);
    array_push($json, $json_item);

    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

For now I added a static json to it as an input data.
I saw that angular returns a value after http get and post so what I want to achieve is to return the json with the ID that was added into the database. I retrun this id with SQL returning contact_id, and I want to insert it into the json but I have no idea how.
After I insert that item into json I want it to look like this

```
{"contact_id":"1","contact_firstname":"Daniel","contact_lastname":"Pacuraru","contact_email":["pacurarudaniel@gmail.com","hello@pacurarudaniel.com"]}
```

Practically to add `"contact_id":"1"` into the json. Thank you, Daniel.

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks. not to mention not normalized.

Comment: could you tell me what could i fix in order to be ok ?

Comment: there is plenty of documentation on the web.

Comment: but i mean how could i insert a json item int othe json bbecause what i tried, does not work $json_item = 'contact_id' => addslashes($row['contact_id']);
    array_push($json, $json_item);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove line:

```
$json_item = 'contact_id' => addslashes($row['contact_id']);
array_push($json, $json_item);
```

Add line:

```
$json_item = array('contact_id' => addslashes($row['contact_id']));
$json = $json_item + $json;
```

It will get the contact_id to the first index. But if you want it on last index then ignore lines above and do:

```
$json['contact_id'] = addslashes($row['contact_id'])
```

Comment: i dont know who voted you down but i used your idea and it works great ! thank you very much!

Comment: It probably was the guy who posted before me and deleted his post. It was wrong :P

Answer (score 1):

It works for me.

```
<?php

    $textdata = '{"contact_firstname":"Daniel","contact_lastname":"Pacuraru","contact_email":["pacurarudaniel@gmail.com","hello@pacurarudaniel.com"]}';
    /*
    Finding contact_id ...
    $contact_id = 1; // example

    */
    $contact_id = 1;
    $json = json_decode($textdata,true);
    $json = array('contact_id'=>addslashes($contact_id)) + $json; 
    echo json_encode($json);
```

The result :

```
{"contact_id":"1","contact_firstname":"Daniel","contact_lastname":"Pacuraru","contact_email":["pacurarudaniel@gmail.com","hello@pacurarudaniel.com"]}
```

Based on your code :

```
<?php
    $textdata = '{"contact_firstname":"Daniel","contact_lastname":"Pacuraru","contact_email":["pacurarudaniel@gmail.com","hello@pacurarudaniel.com"]}';
    $json = json_decode($textdata, true);
    //$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbport = "5432";
    $dbname = "fixevents";
    $dbuser = "postgres";
    $dbpass = "123";
    $connect = pg_connect("host=" . $dbhost . " port=" . $dbport . " dbname=" . $dbname . " user=" . $dbuser . " password=" . $dbpass);

    $query = "INSERT INTO contact (contact_firstname, contact_lastname, contact_email) VALUES ('" . addslashes($json['contact_firstname']) . "', '" . addslashes($json['contact_lastname']) . "', '" . addslashes(implode(',,,', $json['contact_email'])) . "') RETURNING contact_id";
    $result = pg_query($connect, $query);

    $row = pg_fetch_array($result);
    $json_item = array('contact_id' => addslashes($row['contact_id']));
    $json = $json_item + $json;
    echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: yes it works for me too, i already done it and it's just great ! thank you so much !